# Changing UIImageView image and save it using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I've been working on an application that allows the user to switch UIImageView image with the touch of a button. To be more specific, I have two images saved that when you press a button, the UIImageView image changes. I have no problem with that. The problem is that when I close the app, the image resets to the image I had initially setup as initial UIImageView image.

I was wondering, is there a way to keep the image that was last selected? In other words:

- When the app starts, the image is set to image1.
- User presses button, image changes to image2
- User closes the app and reopens it, image2 is still the background unless user taps button again

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!


let lightBG = UIImage(named: "bg1.jpg")
let darkBG = UIImage(named: "bg2.jpg")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func changeBG(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(backgroundImage.image == lightBG){
        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
    }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = lightBG
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the selected image in a couple of ways. One is to save the name of the image in the user defaults either when the view is exiting or when the image is changed by the user.

Here is how to save it when the user changes the image:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

let kBGImageNameKey = "bgImageName"

let lightBG = UIImage(named: "bg1.jpg")
let darkBG = UIImage(named: "bg2.jpg")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let name = defaults.stringForKey(kBGImageNameKey) {
        if (name == "bg1.jpg") {
            backgroundImage.image = lightBG
        } else {
            backgroundImage.image = darkBG
        }
    } 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func changeBG(sender: AnyObject) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if(backgroundImage.image == lightBG){
        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
        defaults.setObject("bg2.jpg", forKey: kBGImageNameKey)
    }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = lightBG
        defaults.setObject("bg1.jpg", forKey: kBGImageNameKey)
    }
}

}
```

This is just one way of doing this just to set you in the direction.

Comment: Yes I tried all of them. This one was the one I understood the most because of your little explanation at the top. Since I have the UIImageView in the storyboard with bg1, your answer helped me. Thank you! (:

Comment: Glad I could be of help :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

     // Initially Check your `NSUserDefaults` key is empty or not 

       if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SaveImage") != nil  
   {
    // If it is not empty , load the `NSUserDefaults` Image
   backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SaveImage"))

   }
else
 {
  // if above condition is not statisfy load the normal Image
  backgroundImage.image = lightBG
  }
}


 @IBAction func changeBG(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(backgroundImage.image == lightBG){
        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
           }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = lightBG

    }

// On your button click , load the last selected Image , thats all
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(backgroundImage.image, forKey: "SaveImage")


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func changeBG(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(backgroundImage.image == lightBG){
        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("bg2.jpg", forKey: "BACKGROUND_IMAGE_NAME")
    }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = lightBG
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("bg1.jpg", forKey: "BACKGROUND_IMAGE_NAME")
    }

  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   var imageName: String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("BACKGROUND_IMAGE_NAME")
   if imageName.characters.count != 0 {
      let imgBackGround = UIImage(named: imageName)
      backgroundImage.image = imgBackGround
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to save a `Boolean` in `NSUserDefaults` rather than the whole image.

```
@IBAction func changeBG(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(backgroundImage.image == lightBG){
        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "IMAGE_DARK_SET")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "IMAGE_LIGHT_SET")
    }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = lightBG
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "IMAGE_LIGHT_SET")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "IMAGE_DARK_SET")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("IMAGE_LIGHT_SET"){

        backgroundImage.image = lightBG

    }else if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("IMAGE_DARK_SET"){

        backgroundImage.image = darkBG
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You'll have to set the other to to false when setting one to true. Or just use one key and set to either true or false. Your current solution will result in both being true after two switches and will always set to light bg.

Comment: @kRiZ Oops! Forget! thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code